# How to count how many times a method was invoked with Junit and Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this method that I want to test inside ProductService:

```
@Override
    public void validateUpdate(Product product, Product modifiedProduct, List<FieldError> errors) throws AppException {
        if(modifiedProduct == null || product == null) {
            addError(errors, "product", "Product cannot be null");
        }else {
            validateName(modifiedProduct.getName(), errors);
            validateShortDescription(modifiedProduct.getShortDescription(), errors);
            validateDescription(modifiedProduct.getDescription(), errors);
            validateRegularPriceAndPromotionprice(modifiedProduct.getRegularPrice(), modifiedProduct.getPromotionPrice(), errors);
            validateCategory(product.getCategory(), errors);
            validateCategoryMatches(product.getCategory(), modifiedProduct.getCategory(), errors);
            validateStore(product.getStore(), errors);
            validateSku(modifiedProduct.getSku(), errors);
            validateWeight(modifiedProduct.getWeight(), errors);
            validateQuantityInStock(modifiedProduct.getQuantityInStock(), errors);
            validateNotifyLowStock(modifiedProduct.getNotifyLowStock(), errors);
        }
    }
```

But I just want to create a test to verify if all the method are being called.
The first one would be to see if the addError method is called once:

```
@Test
    public void testValidateUpdateProduct() {
        ProductService productService = Mockito.mock(ProductService.class);
        List<FieldError> errors = new ArrayList<FieldError>();
        productService.validateUpdate(null, null, errors);
        Mockito.verify(productService, Mockito.times(1)).addError(errors, "product", "Product cannot be null");
    }
```

But then I get:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
productService.addError(
    [],
    "product",
    "Product cannot be null"
);
-> at ca.edooby.edoobyapi.service.ProductServiceTest.testValidateUpdateProduct2(ProductServiceTest.java:1022)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
productService.validateUpdate(
    ca.edooby.edoobyapi.model.Product@d2ca3a9,
    ca.edooby.edoobyapi.model.Product@2b26d289,
    []
);
```

Comment: If you are testing something, you can't mock it (or rather shouldn't). This is more of a test design error than anything else - you should either split this validator into multiple classes (single responsibility principle, might be taken a bit to the extreme admittedly) or verify side effects of validation (feeding incorrect data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to verify behaviour of a mocked object. There are several reasons why this is a bad idea:

1. By default mockito replaces all calls to actual methods with stubs (which do nothing)
2. Your tests are highly coupled to the internal implementation of the class
3. All the smaller validating methods that are called have to have loosened visibility level (at least to package-private) for that to work
4. It shows that the class has multiple responsibilities - ideally you'd have a lot of smaller validators which are then tested separately, and then you can unit test the composing validator - by whatever method you fancy (you can then fully stub out the sub-validators).

Nevertheless what you are trying to do is doable. I'd call it a semi-mocked approach, and as mentioned above - it's an antipattern.

For simplicity's sake let's say that we have a class like this:

```
public class Baz {
    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
       // stuff
    }
}
```

`foo` is the equivalent of your `validateUpdate` method, and `bar` is the equivalent of about just every other validator method called from there.

The test would start with configuring the semi-mock:

```
    Baz baz = mock(Baz.class); 
    doCallRealMethod().when(baz).foo();
```

This addresses the core issue with your test - it did not actually call the original `validateUpdate` method, because mockito by default stubs out all the methods (they don't get called).

From then on the test works as usual:

```
    baz.foo();
    verify(baz).bar();
```

And it passes. Again, I'm not Pope Mockius III the Tester to be some sort of an authority, but you should in general:

- stick to checking the inputs and outputs of the code (it doesn't tie you to the implementation as much)
- if you have to mock/stub stuff, avoid doing that to system under test - this shows that there's something wrong with the design, and that the class can be decomposed further

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs! One question about the design and highly coupled test. I have specific tests for each one of the methods there that validate input / output. So I know they are working. That's why I thought about creating a test that only verifies if the methods are being called as I already know that the methods being called are covered. I'm having some problems understanding when to create simple unit tests against when to create integration tests. If you have some book to refer it would be really appreciated! Thank you once more!

Comment: @Igor" In general when you find semi-mocking handy to not repeat yourself (as here) you should split the class into smaller bits. Whether you want to stick to unit tests (one tested composing class with multiple mocks + separate tests of the mocked classes) or introduce integration tests (here bottom-up approach fits nicely - no mocks at all, all classess instantiated) is a matter of taste rather than hard policy. I'd stick with integration test with simple failing(for instance just invalid name)/passing cases + detailed units.

Comment: @Igor: as to books - I'm currently in delegation and I don't have my library handy. As mentioned above it's a matter of taste rather than a hard policy - depends on the project at hand and how risky the piece of code is. More risky pieces of code should obviously be covered more, just as pieces which are likely to change or which might not be obvious. If you are looking for brief tests I'd recommend going integration tests over detailed units since they show more of a full picture.